# Reading multiple files sequentially group wise

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, glob

I have data inside a directory as follows

```
 IU.WRT.00.MTR.1999.081.081015.txt
 IU.WRT.00.MTS.2007.229.022240.txt
 IU.WRT.00.MTR.2007.229.022240.txt
 IU.WRT.00.MTT.1999.081.081015.txt
 IU.WRT.00.MTS.1999.081.081015.txt
 IU.WRT.00.MTT.2007.229.022240.txt
```

and at first i want to group the data by using similar pattern of 3 files (differ by R,S,T) as follows:

```
IU.WRT.00.MTR.1999.081.081015.txt
IU.WRT.00.MTS.1999.081.081015.txt
IU.WRT.00.MTT.1999.081.081015.txt
```

and want to apply some operations on it

and then i want to read data

```
IU.WRT.00.MTT.2007.229.022240.txt
IU.WRT.00.MTS.2007.229.022240.txt
IU.WRT.00.MTR.2007.229.022240.txt
```

and want to apply similar operation on it.

In the sameway i want to continue the process for millions of data sets.

I tried the example script

```
import os
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import defaultdict

def groupfiles(pattern):
    files = glob.glob(pattern)
    filedict = defaultdict(list)
    for file in files:
        parts = file.split(".")
        filedict[".".join([parts[5], parts[6], parts[7]])].append(file)
    for filegroup in filedict.values():
        yield filegroup
 
for relatedfiles in groupfiles('*.txt'):
    print(relatedfiles)

    for filename in relatedfiles:
        print(filename)
```

However it reads the file one by one but every time i need to read 3 files at a time(i.e by adopting sequence criteria, first of all it would read first three files and then next three files and so on.I hope experts may help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Sort your list of files on multiple keys.

```
import os
files = [f for f in os.listdir("C:/username/folder") if f.endswith(".txt")]
grouped = sorted(files, key=lambda x: (x.split(".")[4:6], x.split(".")[3]))

>>> grouped
['IU.WRT.00.MTR.1999.081.081015.txt',
 'IU.WRT.00.MTS.1999.081.081015.txt',
 'IU.WRT.00.MTT.1999.081.081015.txt',
 'IU.WRT.00.MTR.2007.229.022240.txt',
 'IU.WRT.00.MTS.2007.229.022240.txt',
 'IU.WRT.00.MTT.2007.229.022240.txt']
```

2. Iterate through the sorted list in threes using the [grouper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) recipe from `itertools`.

```
from itertools import zip_longest
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

for f in grouper(grouped, 3): #f is a tuple of three file names
    #your file operations here
```

Comment: What do you mean "reads the file randomly"? I sorted in the required order and saved it to `grouped` and then iterate over `grouped` in threes. This is what I thought you needed? See the output of `grouped`

Comment: @chumunB - Do all the ".txt" files in your folder have the exact same naming convention? If so, see my edited code to get the `files` list programmatically.